# How to change app's theme outside of main?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm making an app, and I found a problem.

On main we declare the primary color of the app, like the code below:

```
        theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
              primary: const Color(0xFF9500c8),
            ),
      ),
```

So on a screen, that its not the main, i receive another color from an api and i'd like to change everywhere in the app to have this new color... but how can i do it if i do not have access to "theme" outside of the main?

Comment: can you explain your requirements clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the MaterialApp with some state management solution that provide the theme to it. If the material apps theme watch or gets notified about the state change (changed theme) then it will get updated throughout your app.

The page where the api call is made can update the state solution you've setup to wrap the MaterialApp.